# Cannot remove a login

Tags: support, bug, login

On the My Logins dialog, I have Google and Facebook logins listed. Attempting to remove the Facebook login results in an error message "You cannot remove your only login".

I haven't tried to remove the Google login so don't know if this affects other identity providers or just Facebook.

This was reported to the Stack Exchange support team, who confirmed they could recreate it and advised I post the issue here.

Comment: looking at that...

Comment: Same issue here. I have just added Google account as mu login option. I'm going to delete my facebook account soon so I wanted switch to google as soon as possible. I'm afraid that I couldn't log to my stack account anymore if my facebook account was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Your "login" in this case - the one the system thinks you're trying to remove - is your *email*.

Since there's only one email, shared between both Google and Facebook, it won't let you remove it.

There's no user-facing functionality to remove just one of the providers attached to that email; it wouldn't even really make sense: since we trust these providers to verify that you own the email address, removing one doesn't actually stop you from logging back into your account with it in the future.

I agree that this a bug, because the UI sets up expectations that it then doesn't fulfill. But the "solution" here is probably a UI change, one that just displays a single email address and then lists the providers you've used with it in the past. We *kinda* had that at one time though, and it was just as confusing in a bunch of other scenarios - so this is one of those areas where we're probably gonna keep ignoring the situation until some UI wizard figures out a better way of displaying this stuff.

In the meantime, if you *really* need to remove a provider (let's say you change the email address associated with your Facebook account), email us and, linking to this post, ask us to remove one specific login provider while preserving the email address.